# Check if data has been added using timestamp mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

I want to replace the sensor.reading == null statement. With an statement which checks previous timestamp
and new timestamp to check if all the sensors have pushed data.
I want to check if a sensor has not pushed any data to the db by checking the timestamp.
But I am not sure how to do this in JavaScript because it is async. I have a sensor table in the db which also has a timestamp. I am using mongodb as a DBMS. And this is in JavaScript.

```
http.get('http://localhost:3000/stream', function (res) {
var body = '';

//Start of request
res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk;
});

var query = sensorManager.find({});
query.exec(function (err, sensors) {
    if (err) return handleError(err);
    check = sensors;
});


//End of request
res.on('end', function () {
    var data = JSON.parse(body);

    check.forEach(function (status) {
        data.forEach(function (sensor) {
            if (sensor.sensor_id == status.sensor_id && sensor.sensor_type == status.sensor_type) {
                if (sensor.reading == null) {
                    var options = {
                        uri: 'http://localhost/api/nodemanager/' + status._id,
                        method: 'PUT',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        json: {"interval": status.interval + 1}
                    };
                    request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                    });
                    if (status.interval == 3 && status.status == "active") {
                        var options = {
                            uri: 'http://localhost/api/nodemanager/' + status._id,
                            method: 'PUT',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            json: {"status": "intermittent failures"}
                        };
                        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                        });
                    }
                    if (status.interval == 30 && status.status == "intermittent failures") {
                        var options = {
                            uri: 'http://localhost/api/nodemanager/' + status._id,
                            method: 'PUT',
                            headers: {
                                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                            },
                            json: {"status": "inactive"}
                        };
                        request(options, function (error, response, body) {
                        });
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I run a query to get the old timestamps of the sensors

after the pull I run the query again to get the new time stamps

but the timestamp is always the same because the recheck happens before the insert is done because the insert method is async. Even when I call the recheck method after the insert method.

Comment: Why don't you use Mongoose? It returns a document if it was inserted correctly, or an error otherwise. `Model.save( (error, document) => { if(error || !document) console.log("Something went wrong") })`

Comment: "the" api? What api?

Comment: Of course it does, but why aren't you using Mongoose in this API? Send data, insert it using Mongoose, return the doc if it was successful, job done

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the timestamp via "new Date". More infos and examples [here.](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/)

Sample Code:

```
db.products.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $set: { item: "apple" },
     $setOnInsert: { dateAdded: new Date() }
   },
    { upsert: true }
)
```

And then you just perform a query to find your outdated sensors.

Comment: Then you just to check the id or name of the sensor - and when the last value has been added. So you know if the sensors are outdated.

But to acutally help you, it would be nice to know about how many sensors we talk and when the data gets old?

Comment: Why don't you check in a separate method? Just run a query and trigger an alarm (or what you want to do), when the data is outdated. Do you have experience in MongoDB and JavaScript? What do you want to do with the data (maybe only displaying in a client app)?

Comment: If the timestamp is actually written via new Date() to the db and you read the value from the db, there has to be a difference.

Comment: For example i saved the last contact of a device in the db and then compared it with the current date - if it was older than 30 sec, i considered the data is old.